# retrieving objects from another model

Tags: django, django-models

I have this situation:

```
class Item (models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(MaxLenght=15)

class ItemIsHired(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    isHiredNow = models.BooleanField(null=False)
```

The thing is that I want to retrieve all the Items that are hired right now, but if I make a query using `ItemIsHired.objects.filter(isHiredNow=True)` I will get objects from the `ItemIsHired` class when I want the objects from the Item class related to them.

Comment: This structure doesn't make sense. A ForeignKey is a one-to-many relationship; it means that you can have multiple ItemIsHired for each Item, so it would be possible to have any number of both True and False values for isHiredNow for any item.

Comment: And if i want to get the last entry for each item?
I need to get certain objects from a table in wich that objects are refered.
That's the point of the question. There's a way to do that?

Comment: What determines the ordering? Is there a timestamp on that model?

Comment: What im trying to do is to navigate backwards trough the FK.
I have a model A with a FK to another B model, and i need to list all B that verify a certain A condition

Comment: So query Bs and use the double-underscore syntax, as described in the tutorial and the [field lookups documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).